# Adding a variable to a join table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm struggling to figure out how I can add a convenience data column to a join table to use for evaluation. 
Sorry if the terminology is incorrect, I'm a bit of an SQL newbie.

For this query structure:

```
SELECT t1.id 
    FROM 
        table1 t1 
    INNER JOIN 
        table2 t2 ON t1.c2 = t2.c1 
    WHERE 
        t1.c5=5;
```

...I would like to add a column in the join table that is calculated using a function of a few of `t1`s columns. For example, the `sum` of `t1.x`, `t1.y`, `t1.z` in a variable called `score` that can then be referenced in the `WHERE` clause.

The reason behind wanting to do this is it will be referenced multiple times and will reduce verbosity and help readability.

I presume it will look something like:

```
SELECT t1.id 
    FROM 
        table1 t1 
    INNER JOIN 
        table2 t2 ON t1.c2 = t2.c1 
        -- function(t1.x, t1.y, t1.z) as score
    WHERE 
        t1.c5=5;
        --AND score ...
```

Using PostgreSQL 9.3

Comment: I think the first function you want to add should go to the select clause instead of the inner join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `score` is calculated from the `t1` columns, then use a subquery on `t1`:

```
SELECT t1.id 
FROM (select t1.*, function(t1.x, t1.y, t1.z) as score
      from table1 t1 
     ) t1 INNER JOIN 
     table2 t2
     ON t1.c2 = t2.c1 
WHERE t1.c5 = 5 AND
      t1.score . . .
```

Answer (score 1):

A good option would be to use the having clause.

```
Select t1.id, SUM(t1.x + t1.y + t1.z)
FROM table1 t1 inner join table2 t2 on t1.c2 = t2.c1
WHERE t1.c5 = 5
GROUP BY t1.id
Having SUM(t1.x + t1.y + t1.z) = ...
```

Or, you could do a sub-query in the from clause. The below code makes some assumptions on structure.

```
SELECT t1.id 
    FROM 
        (Select SUM(t1.x + t1.y + t1.z) as score, t1.c5, t1.c2, t1.id
         FROM table1 t1
         GROUP BY t1.id
        ) t1
    INNER JOIN table2 t2 on t1.c2 = t2.c1

    WHERE 
        t1.c5=5
        And t1.score = ...
```

Comment: I believe the first query is going to generate an error in Postgres, because it has no `group by` clause.